# Warning: some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to resolver = "2"

Tags: pallet

I build some custom pallet and today I saw following warning while building my node and I would like to ask: only me has the warning?

```
warning: some crates are on edition 2021 which defaults to `resolver = "2"`, but virtual workspaces default to `resolver = "1"`
    note: to keep the current resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "1"` in the workspace root's manifest
    note: to use the edition 2021 resolver, specify `workspace.resolver = "2"` in the workspace root's manifest
```

I ask because I want to avoid too much chaos while building.

Comment: I was about to ask this a few days ago, but when I changed to the stable compiler it disappeared

Comment: I came to the conclusion it did not break anything important

Comment: Both resolver 1 and 2 will generate binary identical wasm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the following to your workspace `Cargo.toml`:

```
[workspace]
resolver = "2"
```

[Here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#feature-resolver-version-2) are more information on this new resolver. You want this as crates of Substrate are requiring to use this resolver, otherwise you will see weird errors ;)